# named_scopes and all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I'm on Rails 2.3.5. Inside my application a user could book one or more time slots for a specific day. I've defined this named_scope in my Slot model:

```
  # day time slots
  named_scope :for_day, lambda { |day|
    if !day.blank?
      { :conditions => ['day_of_week = ?', day] }
    end
  }
```

I use that to retrieve all the "time slots" available in a day.
However I have a page where I'd like to see all the booked slots (in other words, other user's slots too).

So when I call the `/slots` url I would like to get every booked slot, when instead I call /user/2/slots I need only those for user 2.

I added this route `map.resources :users, :has_many => :slots` to my routes.rb
and this code to my slots_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    if params[:user_id]
      @slots = User.find(params[:user_id]).slots
    else
      @slots = Slot.all
    end
  end
```

Please note that a user could also see another user's booked slots alone.

Now when I try to use the :for_day named scope above for the Slot.all array I get:

`undefined method for_day for #<Array:0x104441f60>`

I was able to fix It adding `named_scope :all, :conditions => {}` to the Slot model, but It's seems a weird solution to me.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `all` method returns an array (as opposed to an association object, which is returned by your `named_scope :all`), so you can't call `for_day` on it.

However you can call named scopes directly on the class you defined them for, so just doing `Slot.for_day(day)` (without `.all`) will solve your problem.